# How can I *exit* multi-cursor mode in VSCode from the keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It's nice that Visual Studio Code has a multi-cursor mode, and it's nice that it is possible to access it solely from the keyboard (although it would be much better if it worked according to native UI patterns on the Mac, but that's a different matter).

What's really frustrating, though, is that it ***seems*** to require using the mouse to get out of it.

Is there any keystroke that natively exits from multi-cursor mode?

Is there any command that does this that can have a keystroke bound to it?

Is there any extension that allows you to exit multi-cursor mode solely using the keyboard?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is the default setting, enabling <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>escape</kbd> to exit multi-cursor mode:

```
{ "key": "shift+escape",          "command": "removeSecondaryCursors",
                                     "when": "editorHasMultipleSelections && textInputFocus" },
```

So I've added the following to my own configuration, to enable the much more intuitive <kbd>escape</kbd> to exit multi-cursor mode:

```
{ 
  "key": "escape",      
  "command": "removeSecondaryCursors",
  "when": "editorHasMultipleSelections && textInputFocus" 
},
```

Comment: For those who use Vim extension, an improvement is

```json
{ 
        "key": "escape",
        "command": "removeSecondaryCursors",
        "when": "editorHasMultipleSelections && textInputFocus && vim.active && vim.mode == 'Normal'" 
    },
```

this will allow to exit from insert mode and yet have multiline cursor in normal mode. i.e.  Only exists multi cursor in normal mode.

Answer (score 6):

Simply type `Esc` when there is no text selected, just multiple cursors.

[image: Esc button reduces the three cursors to one]

Comment: This does not work (for me, at least) without customizing the keybindings.

Comment: @iconoclast I have to double-press Esc in some cases.

Comment: Works for me out the box. I guess this is thanks to this default key binding: `{"key": "escape", "command": "cancelSelection", "when": "editorHasSelection && textInputFocus"}`

Answer (score 0):

I use ESC when I'm on the keyboard and a single mouse click (without the Alt modifier) when my hand is on the mouse. Even if ESC is eaten by an extension (or a bad setting) the mouse always works.

Answer (score 0):

Using the escape key (as suggested above) is the correct answer. That being said...

If you are using linux and also have the escape key remapped at the operating system level, then there is an issue where VSCode will not correctly catch the key press on the (remapped) escape key. The fix is to add the following line to your `settings.json` file and restart VSCode:

```
"keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode",
```

For more details, see this issue on the VSCode GitHub:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23991